# Using dynamic named lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following code:

```
areas=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
filas=np.sqrt(len(areas))
i=0
matriz=[]
while i < filas:
    globals()['L%s'%(i+1)]=areas[(len(areas)//filas)*i:(len(areas)//filas)*(i+1)]
    matriz.append('L%s'%(i+1))
    i+=1
```

This just gives me:

```
matriz=['L1','L2','L3']
```

What I want to get is:

```
matriz=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I wanted something general because actually I have to do this in a list of 1600 elements, so I will have up to L40 lists in my list "matriz".

Comment: How does `L` enter into this?

Comment: With `globals()['L%s'%(i+1)]=areas[(len(areas)//filas)*i:(len(areas)//filas)*(i+1)]` I'm creating lists like `L1 = [1,2,3]; L2 = [4,5,6]; L3 = [7,8,9]`

Comment: @StephenRauch The extremely questionable `globals` usage.

Comment: Sorry for that, I know it's horrible to look at, I have like 0 experience... I would appreciate ways to improve my code though.

Comment: What you are trying to do is common for newer programmers.  But it is almost always a bad idea.  The duplicate link contains links to other duplicates.  Lots available to read.

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry for the duplicate, I swear I spent a lot of time trying to find what I posted, thank you for the information. I'll read what you suggest.